# Bring coca leaves from South America to Europe

Tags: legal, europe, food-and-drink, argentina, drugs

Soon I will fly back home from Argentina. Here in some places (as in other Andean countries) coca leaf from Erythroxylum Coca are legal and of common use for plenty of reasons, mainly historical. You can find it everywhere and usually sold in packets of about 20g of leafs. My question is: can I fly back to Europe (Buenos Aires->Madrid->Milan) with two packets of those leaves?

Comment: The fact that they're legal in Argentina doesn't mean they are in Europe...

Comment: See this link which although not official strongly suggests that coca leaf is illegal in Italy https://it.tripadvisor.ch/ShowTopic-g294311-i818-k10381021-Gadgets_e_souvenir-Peru.html (it is in Italian but since you are going home to Milan I assume you are interested in importing it to Italy.